# getting this exception [CFURL release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1049530 when debugging iPhone application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Title says everything.

I've enabled NSZombieEnabled for project.

cheers

Comment: How is the justArray property being declared? As a retain property?

Comment: Is wJustUrl a local filesystem address or a network address?

Comment: Can you label your NSLog() statements, and show the output? Is the over-release happening in the middle of the posted code? I have a feeling that whatever the problem is, it's not in THIS code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you calling [justURL release] anywhere?  You shouldn't, since it is autoreleased for you...

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark (haven't bothered to test how it would behave), but are you certain that -URLWithString: is returning a value? Are you seeing the URL in the log after the NSLog?

If -URLWithString: doesn't like the URL (for example, if there's a space in it) then it will return a nil value, which -arrayWithContentsOfURL: might not like.

Answer (score 0):

I did the exact same thing, e.g. calling [justURL release].. commented that and voila!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and fixed it.

Firstly i create my url:

```
contentUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:step.Videolink];
```

and afrer i release it

```
[contentUrl release];
```

Its rough mistake, because `NSURL URLWithString:` create `autorelease` object.